# Change df.columns.names for multiindex columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to rename one of my levels in a multiindexed columns dataframe in pandas.

```
df.columns.names
```

gives me

```
FrozenList(['level0', 'level1'])
```

I want to rename 'level0' to 'main'.

I have tried different approaches, none works:

```
 df.columns.set_names('findingkey', level=0, inplace=True)
```

gives me     `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

I also tried to do it directly:

```
df.columns.names[0]='main'
```

with output: `TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.columns.names = ['main', 'level1']
```

Or

```
df = df.rename_axis(['main', 'level1'], axis=1)
```

Comment: First one works, I am just puzzled that df.columns.names[0]='main'
 did not work then...

Comment: Hmm I think error is clear -  `'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations`, so only assign all new values works.

Comment: and there is no method that allows to rename only one?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: only `df.columns.names = ['main'] + [df.columns.names[1]]` - but it is a bit crazy ;)